# What's the professional standpoint on including a core PHP script in all other PHP scripts?

Tags: php

I can imagine that in larger projects some things tend to get redundant in most PHP scripts. From the top of my head: Including classes, authentication, including a configuration file, setting include path etc.

As far as my imagination has run, this should be done in absolutely every PHP script in the project. This would then be simplified by adding a "core" PHP script that handles all this.

However, from this very site, I can quote

> > "I am planning on creating a PHP file "core.php" that will be included at the top of EVERY SINGLE PHP file in the project. This file will handle authentication and include base functions. Thoughts?"
>
> I cannot stress enough 'do not do this'. There is a rule among experienced PHP developers that any project with a large core.php file that it's a warning sign of bad development and should be best avoided.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012201/how-do-i-structure-my-php-project)

Which leaves me at a loss. Is it better to redundantly write the same 20-30 lines of code on top of every file than to embrace DRY coding?

Any clarification would be appreciated!

---

I'll quickly clarify here. The "Front Controller pattern" which I actually use when writing most websites and applications does not really fit the type of project I'm talking about. Well actually it does, and I already intend to use it, but my project also contains a lot of PHP scripts that should return content for Ajax requests. It is those PHP scripts that my question regards.

Comment: Most people use a framework. While writing your own is a good educational exercise, you're probably best off using a common one (e.g. Zend Framework) professionally.

Comment: If you don't mind reading source code, Kohana is also a great framework.

Comment: I'm actually hoping this question will end up becoming "why not to do this" instead of cargo-cult "USE A FRAMEWORK DURR" repetition.

Comment: Also I'm wondering about the "legitimacy" of a "core.php file" that simply includes `include 'config.php'; include 'dblibrary.php'; include 'user.class.php';` (except on multiple lines because you can't put linebreaks in a comment and with more include lines for libraries and classes).  (And dblibrary.php is a actual "approved" DB library like ADODB or MDB2.)

Comment: MiffTheFox: I'm talking about autoloading, not including a bunch of files. I'm not about to load and parse every file in my objects folder for every script I run. :-)

Comment: AJAX requests can be handled equally well with a front controller and a core.php, since both are executed before the main body of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to include 20-30 lines on top of every page, it sounds like it's time for a better architecture. Look into Dispatching/Routing for example. Every request is handled by a central .php file, the Dispatcher, which parses the request and decides which files need to be invoked and loaded.

This is implemented in most PHP frameworks. Play around with one to get a feeling for it.

Comment: I took for granted that my project would run through a central PHP file, but what about the PHP scripts that should return content to Ajax requests? I plan on having lots of those.

Comment: @Codemonkey What difference does that make? :) Routing is great for responding differently to different kinds of requests. Just prefix your AJAX methods with `/ajax/` or add an extension like `.json` and your router can automatically send them to corresponding methods and/or simply change the *layout* in which responses are returned. Provided you employ an architecture that lets you separate concerns to this degree. Again, these are all already solved problems in any decent framework.

Comment: Wow, stuff if starting to make a lot of sense. It didn't click that doing absolutely everything through one file would completely nullify most of the issues I described. If done correctly, checking for authentication in each file can be done in one line anyway, if the scripts check for a global file defined in the router file.

Comment: if the scripts check for a global **variable*** defined in the router file

Answer (score 4):

I recommend taking the same approach as Wordpress, the [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) pattern.

Basically it filters all incoming page requests through index.php. Open up `.htaccess` and you can see that it filters all requests through index.php unless the file or directory already exists. This allows you to parse the URL into sections in any syntax you would like. No need to make different files for different URLs. You can receive example.com/page/1 and map the section at the end to any page.

[Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) is a great library to attempt to understand and master this concept.  It lets you extend classes and implements tons of PHP 5 features.  As an added bonus Kohana is MVC (also HMVC) which is incredibly important for large sites.

Comment: This approach is called the Front Controller pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that answer was against DRY, even though it does not make it easy to see. The author *did* suggest using an established framework, which most certainly takes care of initialization and common application backend features in a centralized and modular manner.

Possibly the author meant "do not produce a homegrown big spaghetti ball of code"; this might be in practice an ill-conceived attempt to building a framework by bunching a boatload of core methods in a monolithic script.

If building (at least in a big part) to learn, I find nothing wrong with trying to centralize your core functions, organize them and start producing a fledgling framework in such a way. Doing this in a thoughtful manner will gain you invaluable practical experience and insight into how applications in general can be architected. Otherwise, I will side with the author of that answer: why have your application suffer from possibly wrong design decisions when there are many fantastic frameworks ready for use?